# I need the code for IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf from ctan.org

Tags: ieeetran

I need the code latex for IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf from

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/

In order to edit this. I didnt find the code I only found the pdf.

Thanks for all.

Comment: You don't edit that but there is also a bare journal file in your directory with comments describing how to use it.

Comment: What would you wish to achieve by editing somebody else's manuscript?

Comment: Michael Shell (author of the class) mentions on the FAQs on [his site](http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/) that he doesn't like to distribute the howto latex because of the difficulties in displaying latex code within a latex document. But, you could always email him and ask.

Answer (score 3):

Michael Shell:

> People sometimes ask for this because they think that the HOWTO code
>   will provide some good examples of usage. Trust me, it won't. The
>   reason is that a lot of special code must be used to display LaTeX
>   code within a LaTeX document. For this and other reasons, I don't
>   release the HOWTO source code.

I fear, this is a clear answer to your question.

If you are having concerns about a special piece of formatting, just ask us in another question or try to contact the maintainer (please note, that Mr. Shell will be getting a lot of input as the IEEEtran is widely used. Make sure to check manuals and FAQs first).

If you really think, this `HOWTO.pdf` would be a big gain for you and others, you should contact Mr. Shell via email and kindly ask for it. Maybe in combination with some offer to help tidying this document up.